# Parse SDK Query has outstanding network connections

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I have followed this tutorial http://attila.tumblr.com/post/21180235691/ios-tutorial-creating-a-chat-room-using-parse-com to create a basic functioning chatroom, however once I had finished and tried to run it I got the error

```
 "Query has outstanding network connections"
```

I was adding it to an existing project where I call another Parse query so I assumed it was that, so I tried creating a completely new project, that produced the same error.

So I downloaded the example project from the tutorial and ran it, it worked fine. After a lot of playing around I tried using the Parse.framework from the tutorial in my project and it worked! That would be fine but I use parts of the SDK that weren't available in the older SDK, so now I'm completely stuck.

I've uploaded the new project here https://github.com/cstokes/ChatTest it includes the new framework (1.1.29) with the error, the version it works it is 0.4.40. I asked over at Parse.com and got simply "Update your projects SDK to a recent version", obviously I tried it with the newest and get the error.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do both a find and a count at the same time with one PFQuery. PFQuery can't do multiple searches at one time. You should make a separate PFQuery for the count.